# java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

Getting error in web service program in my pc but the same code is working fine in other pc. Any solution to this ?

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ServletAdaptor] in context with path [/REST] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory._getMessageBodyWriter(MessageBodyFactory.java:395)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory._getMessageBodyWriter(MessageBodyFactory.java:382)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.getMessageBodyWriter(MessageBodyFactory.java:363)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:266)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1448)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: And your code looks like...?

Comment: Do you have any custom `MessageBodyWriters` that you're registering in your application?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much did you really searched for this.

Java document state specific reason behind this error.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html

I think your jar are mismatching... Jar that you are compiling at local and jar used while running the application at some other location in different. This is basic issue for most of such issue. You can verify version of your jars...

I looked few more options, but people talk about different versions of jars... Please have a better look on your jars.. It might help....